# Discord.js detect user profile picture updates

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to detect if a user has updated their profile picture. But it seems I'm completely stuck right now.

I have tried to look for a solution but I've found nothing. Does anyone here know how to detect a profile picture change ?

Here are my partials:

```
partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENT', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **guildMemberUpdate** event.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (oldMember.avatarURL() === newMember.avatarURL()) {
        console.log("User didn't changed avatar");
    } else {
        console.log(`User changed avatar`);
    };
});
```

When you use the **guildMemberUpdate** event, it only works if the person changes their avatar for the server. If you don't want it to be server specific, you should use the **userUpdate** event.

```
client.on("userUpdate", async (oldUser, newUser) => {
    if (oldUser.avatarURL() === newUser.avatarURL()) {
        console.log("User didn't changed avatar");
    } else {
        console.log(`User changed avatar`);
    };
});
```

Comment: Heya thanks for the answer but for some reason it doesnt seem to work 

I have changed my pfp on an alt account and the bot didnt seem to detect it 

am I missing an intent or partial maybe ?

Comment: When you use the guildMemberUpdate event, it only works if the person changes their avatar for the server. If you don't want it to be server specific, you should use the userUpdate event.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Sorry about the misconception